# BlackBerry PaneManager (MVC) - how to block scrolling out of bounds

Tags: model-view-controller, blackberry

How do I disable the "elastic" scrolling in a BlackBerry PaneManagerModel/View and HorizontalScrollableTitleView/HorizontalScrollableController?

I mean: when I drag the leftmost pane to the right (dragging the title bar), the white background appears, and when I lift my finger, it bounces back.

I find it very annoying, I suppose it's a feature of the PaneManagerView, or the HorizontalScrollableTitleView, can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about adding a `ScrollChangeListener` to the View that adjusts the scroll whenever it goes beyond the bounds?  For example:

```
public void scrollChanged(Manager mgr, int newHorizScroll, int newVertScroll) {
    if (newHorizScroll < 0) {
        setHorizontalScroll(0);
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, but it was a good starting point. I had to intercept the TouchEvent on the controller, and ignore it (return true) when scrolling too far.